# Why pip not installing latest ersion of django

Tags: python-3.x, django, pip, virtualenv, django-4.0

I tried to install django4.0.1 in ubuntu20.14 with virtual environment.

```
pip install Django==4.0.1
```

It showing error as

```
No matching distribution found for Django==4.0.1
```

Previously in the same OS django4.0.1 was installed, but why its not installing now?
I tried many ways
Now it's installing only django3.2.12.
Suggest me a way to get latest version

Comment: What is your Python version? [Django 4](https://pypi.org/project/Django/4.0/) requires Python >= 3.8.

Comment: If you have the last version of python (as @phd mentioned). It is possible that you need to update your pip version. Try with `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` or `pip install pip --upgrade`, after that you will be able of install the last version.

Comment: @phd Yes, its python>3.8 only. initially, it got installed, but after somedays,

Comment: @Jony_23 i tried to create other virtual environment with django4.0.1 its showing that error. now both old and new virtual environments dont have django4.0.1.  pip is upgraded, still same error.